# "A route with the resolved virtual path '~/blah' has already been added." within WCF WebAPI Preview 6

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api, orchardcms

So I'm using WCF WebAPI Preview 6 within my application (Orchard CMS). I'm trying to register a route and I'm constantly receiving:

> A route with the resolved virtual path '~/api/register' has already
>   been added. Parameter name: virtualPath

with the following:

```
var webApiRoute = new WebApiRoute(routePrefix, serviceHostFactory, serviceType) { Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(constraints) };
```

being where it's breaking. I can make the route path anything and continue to receive the same error.

My full method looks like the following:

```
public class WebApiRoutes : IRouteProvider 
{
    private readonly IRegistrationWebApiConfiguration _registrationWebApiConfiguration;

    public WebApiRoutes(IRegistrationWebApiConfiguration registrationWebApiConfiguration) 
    {
        _registrationWebApiConfiguration = registrationWebApiConfiguration;
    }

    public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes() {
        return new[] {
                new RouteDescriptor { Priority = 1, Route = MapServiceRoute(typeof(RegistrationResource), "api/register1006", _registrationWebApiConfiguration.GetInstance())
            }
        };
    }

    public void GetRoutes(ICollection<RouteDescriptor> routes) {
        foreach (var routeDescriptor in GetRoutes())
            routes.Add(routeDescriptor);
    }

    private static ServiceRoute MapServiceRoute(Type serviceType, string routePrefix, HttpConfiguration configuration = null, object constraints = null, bool useMethodPrefixForHttpMethod = true)
    {
        if (configuration == null)
            configuration = new WebApiConfiguration(useMethodPrefixForHttpMethod);

        var serviceHostFactory = new HttpServiceHostFactory { Configuration = configuration };
        var webApiRoute = new WebApiRoute(routePrefix, serviceHostFactory, serviceType) { Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(constraints) };
        return webApiRoute;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

So based on Piotr's comments below, I tried his second bullet. The first did not work. The second one gives the same exception and crashes on the construct for my class:

```
public class MyRestRoute : WebApiRoute {
    public MyRestRoute(string routePrefix, ServiceHostFactoryBase serviceHostFactory, Type serviceType) : base(routePrefix, serviceHostFactory, serviceType) {}

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just grabbed the source and noticed that `WebApiRoute` inherits from `ServiceRoute` (and just overrides `GetVirtualPath`, returning null). So all problems caused by `ServiceRoute` also apply to `WebApiRoute`. The first link I sent you in the answer could be helpful.

Comment: Btw - I'll try to come up with a solution to that today/tomorrow.

Comment: Ever have any luck? I didn't. I moved away from this for now by hosting my WCF in a different domain (and having a different issue, but that's a data issue right now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That also happened with WCF `ServiceRoute`'s some time ago - you might this link helpful: http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/256924.

You could also try:

- Changing the `RouteDescriptor.Priority` to a very high number (eg. `Int32.MaxValue`). This would ensure that your route would be registered before any other route, so it would not conflict with other, 'normal' routes.
- If the former would not help, try creating your own subclass of the `WebApiRoute`, override the `GetVirtualPath` method and make it always return null. It will force the framework to omit that route when generating URLs.

Comment: The first bullet did not work Piotr. I tried that first, but didn't think it would resolve it. I'm currently trying the second.

Comment: I implemented the first bullet as shown above in the Update section and am still receiving the same exception.

Comment: Yeah, the second approach is better, although it's also more work. There could be a bug in WebAPI... Some automagical stuff is definitely happening under the hood in either `GetRouteData` or `GetVirtualPath` methods of `WebApiRoute`, so if I were you, I'd look into the original code.